# Can I get a web element inside another web element?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

**Yo dawg I heard you like web elements...**

So I would like to know if it is possible to find a web element by class, id or any other selector and then inside that find another element by class etc.

**Background**

I have some container with an id that contains a collection of elements I want to put into a list by class, the problem is that if I try to `getElements(By.class)` it will pick up some elements outside that I don't want.

**Attempted**

I have tried doing it with `XPATH`but it feels dirty like hard coding. Since these tests should be robust I thought there must be a better way of doing it.

This code captures elements outside of what I want

```
public double checkStars(){
    List<WebElement> starsOn = driver.findElements(By.className("on"));
    return starsOn.size();
}
```

**Question**

Can I select a web element when limiting the search to inside another web element and how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can find another element inside an element provided that element is child element of that element. something like this:

```
WebElement eleParent=driver.findElement(Locator);
WebElement eleChild=eleParent.findElement(Locator);
```

Be careful if your locator is XPath !!!

Comment: Thats really cool, so i can grab a section of a page and then look for a collection of elements only within that. :) cheers Mrunal, good concise answer

Comment: your welcome. if this solves your issue can u accept it as answer!! so that others can also find it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at CSS selectors. It's generally a faster way of accomplishing this. Here's a simple example for the google.com page. It grabs the two links (`A` tags) in the upper right, Gmail and Images.

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#gbw a.gb_P"));
for (WebElement link : links)
{
    System.out.println(link.getText().trim());
}
```

This CSS selector, `#gbw a.gb_P`, reads as find an element with an id (#) `gbw` that has descendant `A` tags with class (.) `gb_P`. CSS selectors are very powerful tools can do pretty complex stuff and are faster and less brittle (in general) than XPaths.

[CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Comment: Thanks JeffC +1 for good concise answer. My problem is that i have some items on the page with the same css selectors and this wouldn't quite catch them. But still a good answer for someone who has access to modify the html and css. As a tester I can not change it.

Comment: If you can use the accepted answer, where you use two different locators, you very likely can use this answer with a single CSS selector that incorporates both locators is what I was trying to convey. If you provide some HTML and the element you are looking for I can help you build one... if you are interested at this point.